# Froala not breaking line when reaching end

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, froala

I have the following problem

[image: froala not wraping the text]

I did some digging on this matter but no success.

I need to make the editor "break line" or wrap around when pasting a big text or typing it.

Thanks!

Comment: can you update your html code then it will be easy to identify what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that removing the froala editor inside of an

```
<ion-row>
 <ion-item>
  <div [froalaeditor]></div>
</ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

it becomes only

```
<div [froalaeditor]></div>
```